# With Visual Studio Team Services how can I use a variable to specify the branch?

Tags: azure-pipelines

I'd like to use a variable to specify my branch name, is this possible?

Here's what I've tried so far...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSTS build variables is not support in Get source step so far. The Repository and Branch options only can be selected by the pick list currently.

And I post an user voice [Enable user defined variable in get sources step](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/20043169-enable-user-defined-variable-in-get-sources-step), you can vote and follow up.

Comment: That's a shame. It's a blocker to us being able to use VSTS properly for our release process. We have different branches tied to different environments so need separate build definitions for now. I will vote on UserVoice, thanks.